# Matrix decompositions that are applicable to all matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know that the following decompositions apply to all matrices

- Singular Value Decomposition
- QR Decomposition
- Schur Triangularization
- Jordan Decomposition
- LU Decomposition

Are there any other such decompositions applicable to all matrices which are known? Please don't reply with decompositions that are more or less derivatives or variations of the above.

Comment: you mean square matrix

Answer (score 0):

[Matrix decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_decomposition) I think here you have almost all the decomposition of matrices possible.